# nuget pack command doesn't includes Microsoft unity

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to create a nuget package for my library that has dependency on Unity. For that I placed below line in my nuspec file.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency id="Unity" version="[3.5.0.0]" include="all" />
</dependencies>
```

and then executed below command

```
nuget pack MyClient.MyProject.ApplicationData.csproj -Prop Configuration=Release
```

When I use resulting package, at run-time I get error saying, "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20247415/765967) seems to be pointing to similar issue, referring it I copied nuget.config file as suggested in its referred link but that didn't helped. Content of nuget.config file are as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="packages" />
  </config>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
</configuration>
```

My project hierarchy is like this

```
MyClient  
--MyProject  
----MyProj.csproj  
----MyProj.nupkg  
--Packages  
----Unity.3.5.1404.0  
--NuGet.Config
```

I got latest version of nuget with me and this is the first time I am creating a nuget package, could someone please suggest what I might be missing here. Any pointers?

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

I checked that "Unity, 3.5.0.0" package doesn't exists on nuget.org.v3(https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json)

I have tried pack command with below nuspack file.

`<dependency id="Unity" version="5.0.0" />`

`nuget.exe pack "D:\Test.Project.nuspec"`

It created proper package with dependency.

These detail will help: What nuget version this project is using? Where is nuget reference mentions?

1. In package.config and solution file (nuget version 2x)
2. In Project.json (nuget version 3x)